# Ошибка "Файл не найден"

Tags: delphi, графика

Короче такая беда, у меня программа работает на ура. У всех друзей она тупо вылетает. Пишет такое:

Данный файл не найден. Проверьте,что путь и имя файла указаны верно.
Также у тех у кого Delphi установлен.

Все файлы на месте!
У файлов полный путь.
Например:

```
main:=  ExtractfilePath(Application.ExeName);


mediaplayer1.FileName:=(main + 'audio\ak47.wav');
```

[image: картинка]

З.Ы. Файл из медиаплэера привёл как из многочисленных других в image.

Comment: к чему здесь тэг "графика"?

Comment: Вы уверены, что структура папок на других компьютерах такая же как и у вас? Есть ли там действительно папка audio в каталоге, где лежит запускаемый файл?

Comment: да! они есть!

Comment: Могу посоветовать ТС соорудить минимально возможный пример на котором будет падать ошибка (в идеале - кнопка открытия файла на форме и обозначенный файл в папке) и залить на файлохостинг.

Ну или исходники показать. Может проблема в другом месте, как говорит @DelphiM0ZG. 

Кстати, @romanzi вы дебаггером проверяли? Убедились, что падает именно на открытии этого файла?

Comment: если есть возможность поменять исходник на другом компе - установите свойство FileName плеера напрямую и посмотрите что будет

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем загружать куда-то файл полезно проверить его существование:

```
If FileExists(полное имя файла) Then
... // работаем с файлом
```

Может это из-за того, что свойство MediaPlayer AutoOpen=True. Проблема, скорее всего, в компоненте MediaPlayer, он, на мой взгляд, здесь не очень нужен. Если проблема не в плеере, то попробуйте трассировку и напишите код, где эта проблема появляется (вполне возможно, что это и не к этому файлу относится). Для воспроизведения файлов с форматом WAV можно использовать функцию PlaySound(три параметра - первый - имя файла (остальные 2 не помню)) объявлена в модуле MMSystem.

Comment: и как это все поможет решить проблему ненайденного файла? )

Comment: Проблему ненайденного может и не решит, но, по, крайней мере, хотя-бы обработать это событие можно будет. На рисунке не показано что за файл не найден. Может и не к этому файлу ошибка относится.